# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PracticasPHP\limpio\enviar.php on line 52

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estuve probando hacer sumas agregándole condiciones por día a mi sentencia sql, basándome en la que vi anteriormente. Esta es la sentencia:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(total) as 'sum_total' FROM ticket_cabecer_detalles WHERE cod_usu='$codusu' AND fecha BETWEEN $hora_min and $hora_max";
```

Esta es la manera en la que chequeo con la base de datos, que los datos sean iguales y que cumplan con las condiciones. Y como los muestro en pantalla:

```
$res= mysqli_query($conexion, $query); 
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($res); echo ' dia '.$data['sum_total'];
```

El problema es que me aparece una advertencia y un notice cuando envió el form:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
> bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PracticasPHP\limpio\enviar.php on line
> 52
>
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\PracticasPHP\limpio\enviar.php on line 53 dia

¿Cómo hago para resolverlo?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a stack overflow, porfa puedes agregar el código, así se puede replicar el error. Además, te invito a leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que mejores tus preguntas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la documentación de PHP sobre `mysqli_query`

> Retorna FALSE en caso de error. Si una consulta del tipo SELECT, SHOW,
> DESCRIBE o EXPLAIN es exitosa, mysqli_query() retornará un objeto
> mysqli_result. Para otras consultas exitosas de mysqli_query()
> retornará TRUE.

Por lo que aquí hay 2 cosas a comprobar: si está retornado true o false. Y cual es la consulta final que le estás haciendo.

Seguramente la consulta no sea válida

```
var_dump($query);
var_dump($res);
```